# Joining/Merging two panel data sets with different time periods in R

Tags: r, merge, panel

How do I merge two data frames (panels) that have different time periods? For example, df1 is structured by year and month. The other - df2 - has variable x only by year. I want to add x which are only by year to df1 and create df3.

Thanks in advance!!

Example:

df1:

```
| ID   | Date   | 
|:---- |:------:| 
|   1  | 2010-01|   
|   1  | 2010-02|    
|   1  | 2010-03|      
|   2  | 2010-01|       
|   2  | 2010-02|  
|   2  | 2010-03|
```

df2:

```
| ID   | Date   |  X    |
|:---- |:------:|:-----:|
|   1  | 2010   |   10  |
|   1  | 2011   |   20  |
|   1  | 2012   |   25  |   
|   2  | 2010   |   5   |
|   2  | 2011   |   15  |
|   2  | 2012   |   20  |
```

df3:

```
| ID   | Date   |   X   |
|:---- |:------:|:-----:| 
|   1  | 2010-01|   10  |
|   1  | 2010-02|   10  |
|   1  | 2010-03|   10  | 
|   2  | 2010-01|   5   |  
|   2  | 2010-02|   5   |
|   2  | 2010-03|   5   |
```

Comment: add a year column to `df1$year= lubridate::year(Date)` and then join df1 and df2 tables by year and Date

Comment: @Eric I had to join by year and Date as well as by ID and then it worked out. Thanks!